# how to split post view on the same page in django

Tags: python, django

I have no idea if this question make much sense or not but i am so confused about it. I have a post list view and it is rendering some of the post here.

My question is how can I split the sections of the page.something like this.
[image: explain view]

what should be the approach of making this kind of view.

this is my posts view.py

> posts/view.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Post.objects.all()[:10]
        else : 
            return super().get_queryset()
```

> posts/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from slugger import AutoSlugField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.slug, filename)

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 60)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True ,related_name='children',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=upload_location,
        null=True, 
        blank=True,
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self, slug=None):
        return reverse("posts-detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Comment: Just add some post type in `Post` model and render it according types. One type - one section.

Comment: @SergeyPugach can you please explain i am not getting it i have postes my models code have a look at it what do you suggest . I new to django and little confused too.

Comment: So you have list of posts assigned to categories (1 post could be assigned to max 1 category). And you wanna display all categories and 10 latest posts in each one. Right?

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev  yes this is what i want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have posts assigned to categories. Each post could be assigned only to one category (since you have FK from `Post` to `Category`). And you want **to display all categories and 10 latest posts under each one**.

I see several ways of how to solve that. The easiest one is to extend `Category` model with property, containing the queryset to retrieve related posts in the way you want them for front page.

```py
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


class Category(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @property
    def posts_for_frontpage(self):
        return self.posts.order_by('-date_posted')[:10]


class FrontpageView(ListView):

    model = Category
    template_name = 'frontpage.html'
    context_object_name = 'categories'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # select some categories for frontpage
        # all by default
        return Category.objects.all()
```

and then in template

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>
    <hr />
    {% for post in category.posts_for_frontpage %}
        <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
    {% endfor %}
    <br />
    <br />
{% endfor %}
```

You could also play with `select_related` to reduce number of queries and with `annotate` to get all related posts.

Comment: I tried to put this but this does not renders posts.

Comment: could you try `{% for post in category.posts_for_frontpage.all() %}`? do you have category titles being displayed?

Comment: this gives me error. yes category titles is being displayed.

Comment: Do you get an error after adding `.all()`? If so, then what error do you see?

Comment: @adityakumar please let me know if you need further assistance