# how to query posts by category in django in function based view

Tags: python, django

I have a Post and Category model. Here I want to list posts By category. Category name will be title of the page and post with same category will be rendered under this.
And I have no idea of how to do this.

> This is my model

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from slugger import AutoSlugField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.slug, filename)

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 60)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True ,related_name='children',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=upload_location,
        null=True, 
        blank=True,
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self, slug=None):
        return reverse("posts-detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

> post/view.py

```
def posts_list(request):
    post = Post.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'category': category,
        'title': 'Post list'
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/home.html', context)
```

Comment: Have you added anything to your view? Can you show it? However you can do it with get context in your views.

Comment: yeah i passed both post and category models using context.

Comment: by the way i want to make something like this see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54971221/how-to-split-post-view-on-the-same-page-in-django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you need to add is related_name in your model foreign key,

```
class Post(models.Model):
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='postcategory')
```

Then you need to add multiple category to your same view. You can add it with simple queryset or using get_context_data,

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'all_categs'

    def get_queryset(self):
       return Category.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data()
        context['latest_posts'] = Post.objects.order_by('-date_posted')[0:3] #or simply [:3]
        # This will show your 3 latest posts you can add accordingly
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse('home') #add your path
```

In HTML you need to show it,

```
{% for post in latest_posts %}
    <p>{{post.title}}</p>
    #other attributes
{% endfor %}

{% for ct in all_categs %}
<div>
    <div> {{ct.title}} </div>
    {% for post in ct.postcategory.all|dictsortreversed:"date_posted" %}
       <p> {{post.title}} </p>
       # add other fields
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now its upto you, how you want to render your front end view. I have not tested this code, if you find any error let me know or find answer in SO,

> Note - Django Queryset is Lazy, SO if you have a lot of category, this
>   can slow down your page loading time. So make sure you improve the
>   page speed with caching and other things.

Edit-1: When you want to show two models attributes, you can use get_context_data. If you want to add form, you can add in similar way as well.

Comment: can i add all posts query as well to query latest post inside this. How will i do that ?

Comment: You have date_posted attribute in Post model and Django has `dictsortreversed` for this case. I am editing the answer. You can check Django docs to know more about dictsortreversed

Comment: no not this one . [link](https://yourstory.com/) i want to make something like this as you can see on this page under latest title , these are just random posts but after that it has categories as Startup and all those stuff.

Comment: All right I'm editing the answer. As I have mentioned, you can use get_context_data to do this.

Comment: You can learn more about mixins here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/

Answer (score 0):

If you want this feature in your admin site then you can overreide`formfield_for_foreignkey` method which originally belongs to `admin.ModelAdmin`.

Visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/

and see `ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)` section

Comment: i dont want this in admin field. I want to do this on my homepage.

Comment: You can use filter to get releted post under same category by doing following:
`Post.objects.filter(category__name__contains =="your category title for respective page")`

Comment: i want all this on home page